# Convert ForEach Dictionary Value If Condition And Add Key to List

Tags: c#, linq

May I know how can I convert the following statement to LINQ?

```
Dictionary<Guid, Guid> BatchID_To_RunID = new Dictionary<Guid, Guid>();
List<Guid> BatchIDList_InCase = new List<Guid>();

foreach (var x in BatchID_To_RunID)
{
    if (x.Value == RunID)
    {
        Guid BatchID = x.Key;
        BatchIDList_InCase.Add(x.Key); 
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Is `BatchIDList_InCase` empty before the loop starts?

Comment: Hi, yes it will be empty at the beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the `if` is effectively a filter, suggesting a `Where` call, and the use of `x.Key` is effectively a projection, suggesting a `Select` call. So assuming `BatchIDList_InCase` is empty before this loop, you could replace it with:

```cs
// TODO: Rename BatchID_To_RunID to follow .NET naming conventions
var batchIds = BatchID_To_RunID
    .Where(pair => pair.Value == RunID)
    .Select(pair => pair.Key)
    .ToList();
```

Or using a query expression:

```
var batchIds = (from pair in BatchID_To_RunID where pair.Value == RunID select pair.Key)
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have a dictionary `BatchID_To_RunID` and a variable `RunId`

**Requirement**

> Give me the keys of all items in the dictionary that have a Value equal to RunId.

If you write it precisely like this, the solution is not very difficult:

```
GUID RunId = ...
var result = BatchID_To_RunID         // this is a sequence of KeyValuePair<GUID, GUID>

    // Keep only those KeyValuePairs with a value equal to RunId
    .Where(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Value == RunId)

    // from the remaining keyValuePairs, Select the Key
    .Select(keyValuepair => keyValuePair.Key)

    // and convert this sequence of GUIDs into a List:
    .ToList();
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```cs
 BatchIDList_InCase.AddRange(BatchID_To_RunID.Where(b => b.Value == RunID).Select(b => b.Key).ToList());
```